# How to give request timeout per request in Java Grpc

Tags: java, spring, grpc, channel, grpc-java

I'm creating a Java GRPC client. Here I'm using a managed channel to create a channel and further passing that channel to create a blocking stub.

```
ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(this.getServiceHost(), this.getServicePort())
    .usePlaintext()
    .keepAliveWithoutCalls(this.isKeepAliveWithoutCall())
    .keepAliveTime(this.getKeepAliveTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .idleTimeout(this.getIdleTimeoutInMilliseconds(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .keepAliveTimeout(this.getKeepAliveTimeoutInMilliseconds(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .defaultServiceConfig(this.getRetryConfig())
    .enableRetry()
    .build();
```

While doing retries, if I have given `maxAttempts` as 3, I want to set a timeout for each of the attempts.

In which parameter should I set that value?

Comment: Are you trying to set a timeout per request, or per attempt?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I want to set timeout per attempt

Comment: Per-attempt timeouts are not supported. They might be part of a future effort to add hedging xds support (due to how xds structures hedging, they are related).